# applescript: buttons variables and properties

Tags: variables, button, properties, applescript

I would like to use two simple button clicks to generate variables for "department" and "suite". One button click should create another set of button options based on the returned value for the "department" Why is this not working?

```
--set up departments and suites
property departments : {"Audio", "Video", "Digital"}
property suites_Audio : {"A1","A2", "A3", "TXFR"}
property suites_Video : {"VFX1", "VFX2", "FCP1", "FCP2", "Flame1", "Flame2"}
property suites_Digital : {"MCR", "Encoding", "Store"}


--get suite location
display dialog "Enter your department" buttons departments
set department to button returned of the result
set suites to "suites_" & department
display dialog "Enter your suite" buttons {suites}
set suite to button returned of the result
```

I have a feeling its in the syntax of these 2 lines:

```
set suites to "suites_" & department
    display dialog "Enter your suite" buttons {suites}
```

So clicking the right department should generate a new set of buttons to burrow down to the right suite, from the properties of Suites at the top.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the value of suites with:

```
set suites to "suites_" & department
```

Try:

```
--set up departments and suites
property departments : {"Audio", "Video", "Digital"}
property suites : {{"A1", "A2", "A3", "TXFR"}, {"VFX1", "VFX2", "FCP1", "FCP2", "Flame1", "Flame2"}, {"MCR", "Encoding", "Store"}}

--get suite location
display dialog "Enter your department" buttons departments
set department to button returned of the result

set suite to first item of (choose from list item (my findOffset(department)) of suites with prompt "Enter your suite")

on findOffset(findItem)
    repeat with i from 1 to (count departments)
        if item i of departments = findItem then return i
    end repeat
end findOffset
```